# Reading binary file to find a sequences of ints little endian (permutations)

Tags: python

Try to read a binary file (firmware) with a sequences like

```
\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00
```

Little endian integer 1,3,2,4

Attempt:

```
with open("firm.bin", 'rb') as f:
  s = f.read()


N = 16

allowed = set(range(4))
for val in allowed:
    val = bytes(val)+b'\x00\x00\x00'
for index, b in enumerate(s):
    print(b)
    i = b.hex()
    b= b'\x00\x00\x00'+bytes(bytes.fromhex(f'{i:x}'))
    if b in allowed and set(s[index:index + N]) == allowed:
        print(f'Found sequence {s[index:index + N]} at offset {index}')
```

Above does not seem to work with error:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'
```

Why?

Problem I am trying to solve:

How can I find in binary file sequences like this being 16 ints little endian with values from 0 to 15 i.e

```
[0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15,0-15]
```

**Update 1:**

Tried proposed answer, but no results, where it should:

```
import numpy as np
import sys


# Synthesize firmware with 100 integers, all equal to 1
#firmware = np.full(100, 1, dtype=np.uint32)
#firmware = np.fromfile('firm.ori', dtype='uint32')
a1D = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 11, 13, 12, 14, 15, 0],dtype='uint32')
print(a1D)

r = np.convolve(a1D, [1]*16, mode='same')[8:-8]
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
print(r)
r = np.where(r < (16*15))
print(r)
print(a1D[r])
```

Ideally it should say offset 0, but values would be also fine i.e to print

```
[ 1  2  3  4  6  5  7  8 10  9 11 13 12 14 15  0]
```

Now it outputs:

```
[ 1  2  3  4  6  5  7  8 10  9 11 13 12 14 15  0]
[]
(array([], dtype=int64),)
[]
```

Comment: `f'{i:x}` I do not see `x` declared or set to anything in your current code.

Comment: I meant to use it like this: `>>> i=0x36 >>> bytes.fromhex(f'{i:x}') b'6'`

Comment: @ukBaz I think 1,3,2,4 is just an example. It may be 15,4,9,12 so they’d need a regex that looks for a small number followed by 3 zero bytes with the whole lot repeated 16 times. *I think*. Also, converting to ints may not work if the values don’t fall on 4-byte boundaries.

Comment: yes I would like to find as an end goal all 16 combinations of 0-15 in a sequence as little endian integer i.e result could be sequence in file like 1,3,4,2,5,7,9,8,6,10,11,14,13,12,15,0 as little endian ie b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00 ...etc'. In my code example I look for 4 combinations ... but the concept is similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You refer to the values in the firmware as 32-bit integers so I've assumed that the file can be converted to integers. I've used the Python [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) lib to do this.

I've also understood that you want to find a sequence of 16 unique integers in the range 0 to 15.

My test below iterated over the integers in the firmware file, looking ahead each time and converting that list of 16 integers to a `set` to check the length was still 16.
I then iterated over the set to check all values where below 16.

Here is my test I did:

```py
from secrets import token_bytes
import struct

# Create test data
firmware_ints = 200_000
int_len = 4
data = token_bytes(firmware_ints * int_len)
to_find = struct.pack('<16L', *range(16))
print(f"To find [{len(to_find)}]: {to_find}\n")
hide_idx = 20 * int_len * -1  # find 20 ints from the end
data = b''.join([data[:hide_idx], to_find, data[hide_idx:]])
# End of creating test data

search_max = 16
search_len = 16

# Convert firmware to integers
words = [x[0] for x in struct.iter_unpack('<L', data)]
# Iterate through to find sequence
for idx in range(len(words) - search_len):
    this_seq = words[idx:idx + search_len]
    if len(set(this_seq)) == search_len:
        if all([x < search_max for x in this_seq]):
            print(f'Found sequence {this_seq} at offset {idx}')
```

which gave the output of:

```
Hidden bytes [64]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00'

Found sequence [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] at offset 199980
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there was some issue I don't understand with my original answer. Here's a different approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

# Make repeatable randomness
np.random.seed(89)

# Generate synthetic firmware of 100 values under 20
firmware = np.random.randint(0,20,100,np.uint32)
print('firmware:\n', firmware)
```

I changed the length of the run to 10 instead of 16 so you can more easily differentiate the threshold (which the numbers must be below) from the length of run you are looking for

```
# Find runs of 10 integers under 16
win_len, threshold = 10, 16
window = np.ones(win_len, dtype=bool)
thresh = firmware < threshold

# Results matrix
out = binary_erosion(thresh, window, origin=-(win_len//2))

# Print results matrix
print('Results:\n', out)

# Print indices
print('Indices:\n', np.argwhere(out))
```

**Sample Run**

```
firmware:
 [19  4 13 11  5  8 18  1  7  0 17  6  1  6  7 13 19 17 17  8  5  7 16 18
 16 13 14 14 13  1 18  9  4 18 12  9 18 17 12 10 12 15  3  9 10  0  2 13
 18  3 16  1 14 17 10 15 17  4  2 15 18  1 12  5  4  3 15 11 11  3  7 17
  0  8 19 15  3 15  7  9 16 18 15  1 19 15  3 19 15 16 19 10  5  4  2 19
 15  8 16  4]
Results:
 [False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False  True False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False  True False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False]
Indices:
 [[38]
 [61]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know numpy, but it does not seem to find it. Please see update 1:

Comment: Also 16 elements should not repeat, now I guess it can

Comment: If the elements may not repeat, the convolution will have to sum to exactly 0+1+2+3+4...15, rather than be less than (16*15).  Though that will only be **necessary** condition, not **sufficient** condition so you may need to do additional checks.

Comment: Tried valid mode but seems it didn't help. Don't know how to sum the convolution

Answer (score 0):

As you weren't too keen on Numpy, here's a way with `groupby()` from `itertools`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

# Make repeatable randomness
np.random.seed(89)

# Generate synthetic firmware of 100 values under 20
firmware = np.random.randint(0,20,100,np.uint32)
print('firmware:\n', firmware)

# Find runs of 10 integers under 16
minLen, thresh = 10, 16

# Thresholded firmware to all values < 16
thresholded = firmware < thresh
print('thresholded:\n', thresholded)

offset = 0
for k, g in groupby(thresholded):
    # Make "g" into tuple and get its length
    gtup = tuple(g)
    l = len(gtup)
    # If this is a bunch of "Trues" longer than or equal to 10 elements
    if k and (l >= minLen):
        print(f'WINNER: offset={offset}, k={k}, g={gtup}, l={l}')
        print(f'Original values: {firmware[offset:offset+l]}')
    else:
        # print(f'DEBUG: offset={offset}, k={k}, g={gtup}, l={l}')
        pass
    # Keep track of our offset into the array
    offset += l
```

Note that it generates the same sample data as my other, Numpy-based answer.

**Output**

```
firmware:
 [19  4 13 11  5  8 18  1  7  0 17  6  1  6  7 13 19 17 17  8  5  7 16 18
 16 13 14 14 13  1 18  9  4 18 12  9 18 17 12 10 12 15  3  9 10  0  2 13
 18  3 16  1 14 17 10 15 17  4  2 15 18  1 12  5  4  3 15 11 11  3  7 17
  0  8 19 15  3 15  7  9 16 18 15  1 19 15  3 19 15 16 19 10  5  4  2 19
 15  8 16  4]
thresholded:
 [False  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True False  True
  True  True  True  True False False False  True  True  True False False
 False  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True False  True  True
 False False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
 False  True False  True  True False  True  True False  True  True  True
 False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False
  True  True False  True  True  True  True  True False False  True  True
 False  True  True False  True False False  True  True  True  True False
  True  True False  True]
WINNER: offset=38, k=True, g=(True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True), l=10
Original values: [12 10 12 15  3  9 10  0  2 13]
WINNER: offset=61, k=True, g=(True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True), l=10
Original values: [ 1 12  5  4  3 15 11 11  3  7]
```